# Why does type ls output ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning bash, so this might be a very noobish question, but I don't understand why `type ls` give me the output `ls is aliased to 'ls --color=auto'`, instead of `ls is /bin/ls` which is what I expected.

I haven't changed any settings that could have an impact on this, as far as I know. I'm running my bash commands in an Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS environment through Vagrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very likely because `ls` is aliased to `'ls --color=auto'`. Did you check your `.bashrc`?

```
grep alias .bashrc
```

will give you all the relevant lines.

Remark: you can have all the possible aliases, builtins, functions, etc. by using the `-a` option to `type`:

```
type -a ls
```

will certainly also give you `/bin/ls`.

Comment: Also check the system start up scripts.  `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: iirc, on Ubuntu this is done in user's `.bashrc`.